# How can write the multiple files with sed from pattern matched

Tags: linux, sed

I have the file like this

```
Orange 23 34 56
Apple 23 44 56
Pear 23 44 56
```

I want to use sed so that it moves the numbers after fruit to filename `Orange.txt` and `Apple.txt` in different files

something like

`s -re 's/(^\w+).*//' > \1.txt`

I know i can do in awk but i only want the sed solution no other unix command

Comment: check here:http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/01/creating-files-based-upon-line-number.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way, using `GNU sed`:

```
sed -r 's/(\w+) (.*)/echo "\2" >> \1.txt/e' file
```

---

But why can't you use `awk`. It really trivializes the problem:

```
awk '{ print $2, $3, $4 > $1 ".txt" }' file
```

Or if you have many columns:

```
awk '{ r=$1; sub($1 FS, ""); print > r ".txt" }' file
```

Comment: thanks steve , i just wanted to know if that can be achieved. i was thinking i may not the full power od sed but thats ok

Comment: If you are using GNU sed then: `sed -r 's/(\w+) (.*)/echo "\2" >> \1.txt/e' file` is suffice.

Comment: @potong: Thanks mate. How'd I miss that?

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible in `sed` if you are willing to write down a giant list of all possible fruit in advance.  Then it looks like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/sed -nf

/^Apple /w Apple.txt
/^Durian /w Durian.txt
/^Kiwi /w Kiwi.txt
/^Orange /w Orange.txt
/^Pear /w Pear.txt
/^Pineapple /w Pineapple.txt
/^Tomato /w Tomato.txt
# ... perhaps dozens more lines ...
```

If you can't list all possible fruit in advance, then this is just plain not possible.  Even if you can, though, do you really want to set yourself up to be featured on the Daily WTF?

```
awk '{ print > $1 ".txt" }'
```